# VML tags are not rendering in the "word" document that i am creating in classic asp

Tags: html, ms-word, vml

my classic asp code generates the following HTML (which includes VML tags) which is displaying fine over the browser but as soon as the very same code is used to generate a word document, the word document still generates fine but ALL the vml tags lost! I mean only the html tags are printing fine but vml tags are not!

I tried replacing vml tags with SVG tags but the same result is encountered for SVG tags too!

Note that this issue is occuring only in office 2013, the word document is generating all the vml and html tags fine in office 2007.
We cannot rollback though.

#### html generated by the code pasted below

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"     xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

<link rel=File-List href="xxxtestlink">

<title>TEST VML CHECK REPORT</title>
<style>
...
</style>

<xml:namespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" prefix="v"/>
<style type="text/css">
v\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); }
</style>

</head>
<body lang="EN-GB">

<div class=Section1>

<style>
p { font-family: Arial; color: #505050; line-height: 120%; }
p.spaced { line-height:12.0pt; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
li { margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; color: #505050; line-height: 120%; }
strong { color: #505050; }
table.small { color: #505050; line-height:12.0pt; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-size: 7pt; }
table.small tr { padding: 1.4pt 1.4pt 1.4pt 1.4pt; }
table.small td { padding: 1.4pt 1.4pt 1.4pt 1.4pt; }
table.small td.header-alt { color: #52619E; border-bottom: solid #52619E 1.0pt; mso-border-bottom-alt: solid #52619E 0.5pt; }
table.small td.header-alt-ac { color: #52619E; border-bottom: solid #52619E 1.0pt; mso-border-bottom-alt: solid #52619E 0.5pt; text-align: center; }
table.small td.header-alt-ar { color: #52619E; border-bottom: solid #52619E 1.0pt; mso-border-bottom-alt: solid #52619E 0.5pt; text-align: right; }
table.small td.data-alt { border-bottom: solid #52619E 1.0pt; mso-border-bottom-alt: solid #52619E 0.5pt; }
table.small td.bb { border-color: #505050; }
table.small td.btb { border-color: #505050; }
table.small td.bt-ar { border-color: #505050; }
table.small td.bb-ar { border-color: #505050; }
table.small td.btb-ar { border-color: #505050; }
table.small td.btb-alt { border-bottom: solid #52619E 1.0pt; mso-border-bottom-alt: solid #52619E 0.5pt; } 
table.small td.btb-ar-alt { border-bottom: solid #52619E 1.0pt; mso-border-bottom-alt: solid #52619E 0.5pt; text-align: right; }
</style>
<p class="spaced"><o:p></o:p><v:shape style="position:absolute;width:167pt;height:670.75pt;z-index:-1;mso-wrap-distance-top:5.65pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:5.65pt;mso-position-horizontal:right;mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin;mso-position-vertical:top;mso-position-vertical-relative:margin" stroked="f"><v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:f" inset="0,,0">
<br>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 class="small" style="background:#EDF1F8;width:100%;">
<tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Country</td><td class="data-alt">China</td>
<td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Sector</td><td class="data-alt">Junk</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Transaction type</td><td class="data-alt">Other</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>outburst date</td><td class="data-alt">September 2001</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>another junk</td><td class="data-alt">10.6x 2000 P/E</td><td>   </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Val method</td><td  class="data-alt">Cost less provision</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt"  style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Internet</td><td class="data-alt">-</td><td>   </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Current  Multiple</td><td class="data-alt">-</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt"  style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Enter value</td><td class="data-alt">-</td><td>   </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Equality  value</td><td class="data-alt">-</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-     weight: bold;" nowrap>Role</td><td class="data-alt">Follow</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td     class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Key   mythbusters</td><td class="data-alt">Warnor sisters</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td  class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Board rep</td><td class="data- alt">ChekcName2</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;"   nowrap>Investment manager</td><td class="data-alt">Angoor</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>BEAM</td><td class="data-alt">-</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td></td><td class="header-alt" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap>Number of employees</td><td class="data-alt">90</td><td> </td></tr></table><br></v:textbox>
<w:wrap type="topAndBottom" anchorx="margin" anchory="margin"/></v:shape><v:shape     e="position:absolute;width:315pt;z-index:-3;mso-wrap-distance-top:5.65pt;mso-wrap-distance- bottom:5.65pt;mso-position-horizontal:right;mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin;mso-position-vertical:bottom;mso-position-vertical-relative:margin" stroked="f"><v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape- to-text:t" inset="0,,0,0"><p><v:shape style="width:104.775mm;height:44.979mm"><v:imagedata src="../inc/read-image-data.asp?imageid=7146"/></v:shape></p></v:textbox><w:wrap  type="topAndBottom"    anchorx="margin" anchory="margin"/></v:shape><SPAN>
<p class="spaced"></SPAN><SPAN><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></SPAN></P>
<p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**From my experience. **

Add `space` before `*`. Because `v\: *` is a selector, but `v\:*` is a strange tag name) and add `display` css rule, it was critical for me, then I render the VML in IE:

```
<style type="text/css">
v\: * { behavior: url(#default#VML);display:inline-block; }
</style>
```

Also you can have a misprint here:

```
<v:shape     e="position:absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer ! thanks to Varun Gulati , for anybody who may be struggling with such issue, the solution is to replace the

```
<v:shape></v:shape>
```

with

```
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"></v:rect> tags in the code .
```

regards and thanks to all those who thought over this and/or replied.

Vishal